# subtitleabovelinecolor option not taken into account

Tags: mdframed, optional-arguments

I'm using the `mdframed` package to draw a theorem command.

However, the option `subtitleabovelinecolor` of the subtitle frame is not taken into account, while the command `subtitleabovelinewidth` is.

Here is a MWE with the problem :

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ,xcolor]{mdframed}
\begin{document}
    \newmdenv[
        roundcorner=5pt,
        outerlinewidth=1.5pt,
        linecolor=red,
        subtitleabovelinecolor=red,
        subtitleabovelinewidth=1.5pt,
        subtitleaboveline=true,
        frametitle={Theorem},]{subtitleenv}
    \begin{subtitleenv}
        Some Text\ldots
        \mdfsubtitle{Notes}
            Some Text\ldots
    \end{subtitleenv}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this :

[image: MWE output]

I'm following the guidelines explained in the [manual](http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) at page 11.

Any ideas where I'd be wrong ? I've tried modifying the order of the options, without success.

Comment: use tcolorbox instead of mdframed - it is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @ulrike-fischer, a solution can be achieved by using the `tcolorbox` package.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[breakable,skins,xparse]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{colback=white,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Theorem,enhanced,breakable] 
    Some Text \dots
    \tcbsubtitle[before skip=\baselineskip]{Notes}
    Some Text\dots          
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

And the output is this :

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bug in the file `md-frame-1.mdf`.

The following MWE contains a locally usable fix that corrects the incorrect definitions for both the `framesubtitleabove` and the `framesubtitlebelow` lines of the `framemethod=tikz`. I have added annotations to the code showing what I replaced.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ,xcolor]{mdframed}

\makeatletter

\def\mdf@drawsubtitleaboveline{%
 \rlap{%
  \hspace*{-\mdf@innerleftmargin@length}%
  \tikz\draw[mdfsubtitleaboverule](0,0) rectangle         %<----- replaced mdfsubsubtitleaboverule with mdfsubtitleaboverule 
     (\mdf@templength,\mdf@subtitleabovelinewidth@length);%
 }%
}
\def\mdf@drawsubtitlebelowline{%
 \rlap{%
  \hspace*{-\mdf@innerleftmargin@length}%
  \tikz\draw[mdfsubtitlebelowrule](0,0) rectangle      %<------ replaced mdfsubsubtitleaboverule with mdfsubtitlebelowrule
     (\mdf@templength,\mdf@subtitlebelowlinewidth@length);%
 }%
}

\makeatother

    \newmdenv[
        roundcorner=5pt,
        outerlinewidth=1.5pt,
        linecolor=red,
        subtitleaboveline=true,
        subtitleabovelinecolor=red,
        subtitleabovelinewidth=1.5pt,
        subtitlebelowlinecolor=blue,
        subtitlebelowlinewidth=1.5pt,
        subtitlebelowline=true,
        frametitle={Theorem},]{subtitleenv}

\begin{document}




    \begin{subtitleenv}
        Some Text\ldots
        \mdfsubtitle{Notes}
            Some Text\ldots
    \end{subtitleenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed/issues/34

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the issue on GH. However, this package is quite deprecated (latest commit in 2014) so I've jumped to `tcolorbox` instead.